# How to build Vertica slave?

Tags: vertica

I have a Vertica instance running on our prod. Currently, we are taking regular backups of the database. I want to build a Master/Slave configuration for Vertica so that I always have the latest backup in case something goes bad. I tried to google but did not find much on this topic. Your help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no concept of a Master/Slave in Vertica. It seems that you are after a DR solution which would give you a standby instance if your primary goes down.

The standard practice with Vertica is to use a dual load solution which streams data into your primary and DR instances. The option you're currently using would require an identical standby system and take time to restore from your backup. Your other option is to do storage replication which is more expensive.

Take a look at the [best practices for disaster recovery](https://my.vertica.com/docs/7.1.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/AdministratorsGuide/Recovery/BestPracticesForDisasterRecovery.htm) in the documentation.